# Global Variables Across Multiple Classes Without Getting Redefinition errors?

Tags: c++

Extreme c++ beginner here. I have a global variable i've tried placing into a separate header file, and also into the specific classes themselves. Throughout, i'm receiving a "redefinition" error.

Here are the global variables:

```
enum GRADE {F, D, CMINUS, C, CPLUS, BMINUS, B, BPLUS, AMINUS, A};
const int BAR = 60;
const int MAXSTUDENT = 100;
```

I have them being used and called upon in two separate classes, called student.cpp and course.cpp. They are contained in "global.cpp"

here is the header in student.cpp

```
#include "student.hpp"
#include "global.cpp"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

Here is the header in course.cpp

```
#include "course.hpp"
#include "student.cpp"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

No matter what combination of headers, or attempts to split the global variables into the classes they are being used by, i am getting a "redefinition" error. If i uninclude "#student.cpp" in the course.cpp section, i won't get the error, but i need the student.cpp for the course.cpp to work.

I'm way out of my element, would appreciate any help.

Comment: You almost never need global variables. Find a different and better solution.

Comment: Your redefinition errors are most certainly due to everything else in `student.cpp` that's being directly included into `course.cpp`, and has absolutely nothing to do, whatsoever, with the `const` objects and the enumeration that are defined in `global.cpp`.

Comment: Never include a .cpp file.

Comment: Also when you ask you should also provide the explicit error

Comment: @NeilButterworth Professors orders are to include global variables

Comment: Get a new "professor".

Comment: @SamVarshavchik how would i resolve this?

Comment: @NeilButterworth i'll be sure to withdraw the course and lose my money so i can acquiesce a stack overflow poster, but first i'd like to try and pass the class.

Comment: Question is, do you want to learn C++ properly, or some nonsense your "professor" is messing you with?

Comment: You resolve this by understanding how `#include` statement work, and making the appropriate changes to your code. As it is right now, what you're doing, effectively is compiling the same `.cpp` file twice, all functions get compiled twice, and when linked together you, of course, get duplicate symbols. Which part of this you don't quite understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file `global.h`. In that file you can **declare** your global variables. `enum GRADE` is not a variable but a type. It is important to remember that you can declare types and variables multiple times, but you can define them only once. So do not define them in the header, just declare them. If you want to use the same global variable across multiple cpp files you must declare them with external linkage.

```
/* File global.h */

#pragma once
extern const int BAR;
extern const int MAXSTUDENT;
```

This is an example `student.h`:

```
/* File student.h */

#pragma once

enum GRADE {F, D, CMINUS, C, CPLUS, BMINUS, B, BPLUS, AMINUS, A};

class Student
{
public:
    Student();
    virtual ~Student();
    /* put more members here */
};
```

Here is an example `course.h`:

```
/* File course.h */

#pragma once

#include "student.h"

class Course
{
public:
    Course();
    virtual ~Course();
    void addStudent(Student& student);
private:
    std:vector<Student*> students;
}
```

Then you can choose **one** *.cpp file to **define** the globals.
For example you put them in `student.cpp`. Then you can already use them in `student.cpp`:

```
/* File student.cpp */

#include "student.h"

const int BAR = 60;
const int MAXSTUDENT = 100;

/* definition of student methods ... for example */
Student::Student()
{ }

Student::~Student()
{ }
```

In that case you do not include the `global.h` in the `student.cpp` file.
Also please do not `#include` any *.cpp files.

Put the declaration of your student class into `student.h`, put the definition of methods of the student class into `student.cpp`.

In the `course.cpp` just include `global.h`, `course.h`. But the `student.h` is already included via `course.h`. Then you can also use the global variable in this cpp.

```
/* file course.cpp */

#include "course.h"
#include "global.h"

/* definition of course methods ... for example */
Course::Course()
{ }

Course::~Course()
{ }

Course::addStudent(Student& student)
{
    if(students.size() < MAXSTUDENT) {
        // ......
    }
}
```

Hope that helps you.